# Query Rails Model Based On Altered Attribute Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a filename. I need to find a record with a matching `file_name` attribute.

My problem is that the filename has been transliterated which is a one-way process. There is no way I can *un* transliterate the filename, so I have no other option but to compare based on the transliterated version of the record's `file_name` attribute.

If I was just comparing filenames I would do:

```
Example.where(file_name: file_name}
```

If I could *un* transliterate `file_name` I would do:

```
Example.where(file_name: ActiveSupport::Inflector.untransliterate(file_name)
```

But I can't, so how can I *efficiently* do the equivalent of:

```
Example.all.detect do |e|
 ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate(e.file_name) == file_name
end
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Sk.Irfan Store the transliterated field on a separate column and use the untransliterated field for the lookup. If you can't do that then then I don't have a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another field that holds the transliterated value. Then it is easy:

```
Example.where(transliterated_file_name: file_name)
```

If it's not an option, then it's not very easy. You could replace all to find_each but the values would still need to be compared on the application level.

Comment: damnit... I was about to answer the same :) a `before_save` callback could do the job. Or overriding `file_name=` to fill in the field when the file name changes.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new column would work as Tumas has suggested, but if you're using a database that supports converting a field to ASCII, you might want to consider that option.

**MySQL:**

```
Example.where("file_name COLLATE utf8_general_ci = ?", file_name)
```